# Table 'XXX.pma__tracking' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am very very confused right now, but somewhere along the lines phpMyAdmin has got confused.

```
 SELECT tracking_active FROM `hutber`.`pma__tracking` WHERE db_name = 'hutber'  AND table_name = 'exp_accessories'  ORDER BY version DESC


#1146 - Table 'hutber.pma__tracking' doesn't exist
```

I cannot select db hutber, when I click on any of the tables i got the above error.

**[Edit]**

I then added the `pma__tracking` to the table and now I get this error:

```
  SELECT tracking_active FROM `hutber`.`pma__tracking` WHERE db_name = 'hutber'  AND table_name = 'exp_accessories'  ORDER BY version DESC

  #1054 - Unknown column 'db_name' in 'where clause'
```

How can I fix my DB?

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES; DESC pma__tracking;
+-------------------------------+
| Tables_in_hutber              |
+-------------------------------+
| exp_accessories               |
| exp_actions                   |
| exp_ajw_datagrab              |
| exp_assets_files              |
| pma__tracking                 |
+-------------------------------+
147 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idpma__tracking  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| tracking_active  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pma__trackingcol | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Note: I created pma__tracking... Just so you know why the structure is like that.

Comment: Please provide your database and table structures first. `USE hutber;`  `SHOW TABLES;`   `DESC pma__tracking;`

Comment: Added, see updated question. I'd like to point out, I believe `phpMyAdmin` creates pma__tracking but not in my DB. I believe inside the `phpmyadmin` DB. Something has gone terrible wrong :)

Comment: According to the table definition there are no columns `db_name`, `table_name` or `version`?

Comment: I think I need to start a new question, which if it solves the problem will solve this issue... If I'm right that is.

Comment: Here is the mistake . Table `pma__tracking` do not have the column  `'db_name'`. That is why you got `#1054 - Unknown column 'db_name' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 0):

**1.**  `#1146 - Table 'hutber.pma__tracking' doesn't exist`

---

Since it is listed in `SHOW TABLES;` this could be a mysql permission issue (chmod, chown) in /var/lib/mysql. Ensure pma_tracking has the right permissions

```
chown mysql:mysql /path/to/mysql
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

**2.** `#1054 - Unknown column 'db_name' in 'where clause'`

---

`DESC pma__tracking;` clearly shows that there is no column as `'db_name'`
, `'version'`, `'table_name`' as mentioned select query

Comment: As mentioned, but nobodies fault as clearly its phpmyadmin related but.. `I too had this same problem. clearing cookies and cache worked for me. try it` This fixed it for me. I cleaned the cookies and the problem no longer occurred. If you want, update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Great !! I was anticipating every time you check result you are already clearing browser cookies and cache

Comment: It was a db error... Why would I think about cookies ;p

Comment: As you mentioned `phpmyadmin` which is browser based. An Answer should never be like 'clear cookies and check result' as you suggested me to update

Comment: Totally agree with that :) Comments though? Unless of course it is the answer!